# validate strings separated by dot (.) in QT

Tags: regex, qt, qt4

Can any one suggest me how to validate strings separated by dot (.) in QT basically just like package name in java,

My code goes like this

```
QRegExp rx("^[\\w]+[^\\.{0,1}\\w+$]*$");
rx.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
return rx.exactMatch(package);
```

but I am getting wrong results

Ex:

```
 com.me.test // valid
 com.me.he. // invalid
 .com.me.he // invalid
 com..me.me // invalid
```

Comment: Can you give example text and what you expect to match?

Comment: thanks Pogo , for your interest in answering. I have updted my question , you can get an idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thats because of your wrong use of a character class. Characters that are between square brackets are a character class, so

```
 [^\\.{0,1}\\w+$]*
```

is a negated character class, because it starts with a `^`. This class will match any character that is not one of those characters: ".{},01+$" or that is not in `\w`.

What you want sounds more like

```
^\\w+(\\.\\w+)*$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32gk0)

And by the way, you don't need the `CaseInsensitive` option, because you don't have explicitly written letters in your regex.